# Firefox won't open links from desktop or from e-mail

Tags: firefox

Please help with this problem. From a Google search, it has appeared over a decade ago and as recently as this year, without an apparent solution.

**System:** Firefox 102.13.0esr (the current version on Debian's 'stable' repository) on Debian 10 Buster, KDE desktop.

**Problem:** Any "*.desktop" link or any link in an e-mail opens Firefox to the home page, but not to the website in the link.  If I change the default browser to a chromium-based browser, the websites in the *.desktop and e-mail links all open without any problem in the chromium browser.  What I have tried to date (without any success): changing the value in `about:config` for `permissions.default.shortcuts`, changing the network.dn.disabltIPV6 to "true", changing newtork.sn.disablePrefetch to "true".